# Sentry does not catch Exceptions from Django Templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, sentry

I set up sentry to catch exception from my website.
When an exception happens in python code, I get it in my sentry.
But when an exception happens in django-template code - no message appears.

How can I get details of what’s wrong with my template?

I say about production installation, so I wish not to publish stack trace to my clients.

Comment: What's your `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` (or `debug` from `TEMPLATES`) setting? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#template-debug

Comment: TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

Comment: try to switch it to `True`, while having `DEBUG = False`.

Comment: Can't do it on a production server.

I got a workaround, but do not know the root cause.

In a template I use a compressor:
```
  {% compress js %}
        <script src="{% static 'js/non-existed.js' %}"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
```
if compressed file exists everything works well, but when I forgot to recompress *.js into single file - the problem occurs.

But I still do not understand why Django does not send this error to Sentry.